# AWS Backup Account Terraform Policy Creation Issue: AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-organizations, aws-backup

I have a situation.

I've delegated administrator rights for AWS Organizations to the AWS Backup account. This allows me to create and modify AWS Backup policies, which is exactly what I need.
However, I've run into an issue when attempting to create the policy using Terraform within the AWS Backup account. I'm receiving the error message **"AccessDeniedException: You don't have permissions to access this resource."**
I've already granted access from the AWS main account to the delegated administrator for AWS Organizations policies for both root users and Terraform.

Do you have any idea?

000000000000 -> AWS backup account

111111111111 -> AWS main account

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowOrganizationsRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/Terraform",
          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "organizations:Describe*",
        "organizations:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowBackupPoliciesCreation",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/Terraform",
          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "organizations:CreatePolicy",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "organizations:PolicyType": "BACKUP_POLICY"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowBackupPoliciesModification",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/Terraform",
          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "organizations:DescribePolicy",
        "organizations:UpdatePolicy",
        "organizations:DeletePolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:organizations::352286888395:policy/*/backup_policy/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "organizations:PolicyType": "BACKUP_POLICY"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowBackupPoliciesAttachmentAndDetachmentToAllAccountsAndOUs",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/Terraform",
          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "organizations:AttachPolicy",
        "organizations:DetachPolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:organizations::111111111111:root/*",
        "arn:aws:organizations::111111111111:ou/*",
        "arn:aws:organizations::111111111111:account/*",
        "arn:aws:organizations::111111111111:policy/*/backup_policy/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "organizations:PolicyType": "BACKUP_POLICY"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Long story short: From AWS console i'm able to create the policy, but from Terraform i'm getting that error

Thank you.

Comment: Which credentials are you using when running the same from the CLI, i.e, when using terraform?

Comment: The problem was because of this stupid tags policy, they weren't added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of this stupid tags policy, they weren't added:

```
        "organizations:TagResource",
        "organizations:UntagResource"
```

Like this is working:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowOrganizationsRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "organizations:Describe*",
        "organizations:List*"
        "organizations:TagResource",
        "organizations:UntagResource"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowBackupPoliciesCreation",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "organizations:CreatePolicy",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "organizations:PolicyType": "BACKUP_POLICY"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowBackupPoliciesModification",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [

          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "organizations:DescribePolicy",
        "organizations:UpdatePolicy",
        "organizations:DeletePolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:organizations::352286888395:policy/*/backup_policy/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "organizations:PolicyType": "BACKUP_POLICY"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowBackupPoliciesAttachmentAndDetachmentToAllAccountsAndOUs",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "organizations:AttachPolicy",
        "organizations:DetachPolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:organizations::111111111111:root/*",
        "arn:aws:organizations::111111111111:ou/*",
        "arn:aws:organizations::111111111111:account/*",
        "arn:aws:organizations::111111111111:policy/*/backup_policy/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "organizations:PolicyType": "BACKUP_POLICY"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```